# Drilldown in Pie Chart of hplot R

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, highcharts

I want to get the drilldown feature provided by HighCharts as described [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-drilldown/) using rCharts using the hplot library. An example of the drilldown function provided [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/highcharts/examples.R) is

```
drill_function <- "#! function() {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
        chart.series[0].remove(false);
        chart.addSeries({
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: color || 'black'
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();
    };
    if (drilldown) { // drill down
        setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
    } else { // restore
        setChart(name, categories, data);
    }
} !#"
```

I am novice to JavaScript and any help in this implementation will be really useful for me

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to include `drilldown.js` module from Highcharts in rCharts? Instead of implementing drilldown on your own (`setChart` method).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `highcharter` package which inclue the `drilldown.js`.You can see a demo here: http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/highcarter-drilldown.

Currently I'm working on a funcionality to make more easy make this type of charts.